# Why am I getting "Invalid currency selection: USD for domain iatspayments.com" on submitting a paid event registration?

Tags: civievent, contributions, iats

Using 1.5.3 CiviCRM 4.6.26 on D7. I get the following error: "Invalid currency selection: USD for domain iatspayments.com" when I submit an event registration.

I believe I have the correct server url in NA for credit card payments: https://iatspayments.com/NetGate/ProcessLinkv2.asmx?WSDL

My event page is configured for USD($)

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Fixed. I guess this is pretty simple. Needs the domain prefix "www" in the URL for the "Site URL" (in the Payment Processor Settings) or it won't resolve. Not sure why it throws the odd error description. But, hey, it's working now.

Comment: Hi John - you can mark your own answer as completed - that will take this question to the archives.

Comment: PS - whenever not sure about the correct URLs -> just add a new Payment Processor -> and see what the new defaults are.